# function calling istelf yet not looping

Tags: java, function, inheritance, recursion, overriding

I am new to programming hence unable to figure out this simple code.

What I don't understand in the following code is `onCreate()` is being called by `onCreate()` itself, yet `setContentView()` ie the next statement is being executed. How is that happening?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not calling itself, it's calling `super`'s implementation of `onCreate`.

See [using the keyword 'super'](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) for more regarding the use of `super`.

Comment: Your link refers to some film in Iran!

Comment: but then we overridden the super's implementation of `onCreate() so isn't it its calling the overridden definition?

Comment: @Ricky Lol, crap. Lemme try that again ;)

Comment: @DevanshuPandey No, you're explicitly calling `super`'s `onCreate`. I've fixed the link; consider reading it.

Comment: @Dave Newton That's better. :D

Comment: @DaveNewton Thnx for answering, i understood it now :)

Answer (score 1):

`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` means it's calling the base class constructor.

The method is being called once, hence why `setContentView` executes.

That is, if I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: By using the `overridde`  annotation we overidden the base class `onCreate()' method so isn't is calling the new `onCreate()` method, we just wrote.

Comment: @DevanshuPandey The `@Override` annotation is a compile-time notation that describes intent; it doesn't change the bytecode. It's so if the developer marks a method with `@Override` the compiler checks to make *sure* we're really overriding something.